# Memoir chapter page formatting

Tags: header-footer, memoir, chapters

I am using the memoir class. I have a series of chapters defined, but I need to change the way the chapter title pages are formatted. In particular, by default the text "Chapter X" is spaced a couple cm further down the page than the top line of text on other pages, but I need it to be the same. Also, the page number on those pages is in the center of the footer, while I need it to be in the top corner like every other page.

Is there a simple way to make these changes?

Answer (score 2):

Got it. To fix the page numbers:

```
\makepagestyle{newchapter}
\copypagestyle{newchapter}{simple}
\aliaspagestyle{chapter}{newchapter}
```

To fix the top margin:

```
\makechapterstyle{custom}{%
    \chapterstyle{default}
    \def\chapterheadstart{}
}   
\chapterstyle{custom}
```